# Wrapping text in a multirow, 90 degree oriented cell

Tags: tables, booktabs

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,onecolumn,draft,openany]{report}    
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig, subcaption, siunitx, booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]    
    \begin{subtable}{.60\linewidth}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|l|c|c|c|c}
            \toprule
            \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{age group of susceptible person}}} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{age group of infectious person} \\
            & & \textbf{0-2} & \textbf{2-5} & \textbf{5-10} & ≥\textbf{10} \\
            \cmidrule(lr{1em}){2-6}
            & \textbf{0-2}   & 2.11  & 0.15  & 0.53   & 0.03   \\      
            & \textbf{2-5}  & 0.55  & 0.40  & 0.50   & 0.12   \\      
            & \textbf{5-10} & 0.56  & 3.68  & 3.61   & 0.13   \\         
            & \textbf{>10}   & 0.55  & 0.55  & 0.81   & 1.43    \\       
            \toprule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}%
    \begin{subtable}{.60\linewidth}
      \centering
        %\caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{c|l|c|c|c|c}
            \toprule
            \parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{age group of agent $i$}}} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{age group of infectious person} \\
            & & \textbf{0-2} & \textbf{2-5} & \textbf{5-10} & ≥\textbf{10} \\
            \cmidrule(lr{1em}){2-6}
            & \textbf{0-2}  & 0.75  & 0.80  & 0.98   & 1.0   \\      
            & \textbf{2-5}  & 0.35  & 0.60  & 0.92   & 1.0   \\      
            & \textbf{5-10} & 0.07  & 0.53  & 0.98   & 1.0   \\         
            & \textbf{>10}  & 0.17 & 0.33  & 0.57   & 1.0    \\       
            \toprule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable} 
    \caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: example of MWE]

Is there a way to make these tables look better? 
In particular,

- is there a way to get the 90 degree rotated text to wrap? I tried creating an second empty column but I got errors.
- is there a way to resize the "data" columns... you see the "10" column is slightly larger than the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i correctly understood your question, than you lookingforsomething like this:

[image]

for rotating text in the first column are used packages `makecell` and `rotating`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\settowidth\rotheadsize{age group of}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{subtable}{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{ c >{\bfseries}l *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]} }
    \toprule
    &       &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\makecell{age group of\\ infectious person}} \\
    \cmidrule{3-6}
    &       &   \textbf{0-2} & \textbf{2-5} & \textbf{5-10} & ≥\textbf{10} \\
    \midrule
\multirow[t]{4}{*}[-3ex]{\rothead{age group of susceptible person}}
    & 0-2   & 2.11  & 0.15  & 0.53   & 0.03     \\
    & 2-5   & 0.55  & 0.40  & 0.50   & 0.12     \\
    & 5-10  & 0.56  & 3.68  & 3.61   & 0.13     \\
    & >10   & 0.55  & 0.55  & 0.81   & 1.43     \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
\hfill
    \begin{subtable}{.48\linewidth}
      \centering
       \begin{tabular}{ c >{\bfseries}l *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]} S[table-format=1.1]}
    \toprule
    &       & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\makecell{age group of\\ infectious person}}  \\
    \cmidrule{3-6}
    &       & \textbf{0-2}  & \textbf{2-5}  & \textbf{5-10} & ≥\textbf{10}  \\
    \midrule
\multirow[t]{4}{*}[-3ex]{\rothead{age group of infectious person}}
    & 0-2   & 0.75  & 0.80  & 0.98   & 1.0      \\
    & 2-5   & 0.35  & 0.60  & 0.92   & 1.0      \\
    & 5-10  & 0.07  & 0.53  & 0.98   & 1.0      \\
    & >10   & 0.17          & 0.33          & 0.57          & 1.0           \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

as you can see, i remove all vertical lines. they don't work well with rules defined in the `booktabs` package. also for numbers are used `S` columns from `siunutx` package.

**edit:** some additiona explanation:

- `c >{\bfseries}l *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}` is definition of table columns layout (instead yours `c|l|c|c|c|c`
- `\rothead{...}` is macro from `makecell` package. it is designed to rotate contents of table cells for desired angle. for rotating also had to be loaded the `rotating` package.

  width of `\rotcell` is set by `\settowidth\rotheadsize{age group of}` textlonger that this text macro break into more lines.

  for details see documentation for the `makecell package
- `S` column type is defined in the `siunitx` package. it enable aligning numbers in table columns at decimal points. with option `[table-format=1.2]` is reserved one digit for integers and two digits for decimals. for details see section 5.14 in the package documentation
- notation `*{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}` means that in the table are four columns `S[table-format=1.2]`
- notation >{\bfseries}l`means that in this column all contents are in boldface fonts. with it you not need to use`\texrbf{...} in each cell in this column.

Comment: Thanks, questions what is `c >{\bfseries}l *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}` in your `tabular` heading? and what is `rothead`

Comment: @masfenix, see additional explanation added to answer.